# Using Pusher for Real Time Notifications - Adapting Laravel Implementation to WordPress?

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, notifications

I have a WordPress site where I run guitar courses and I currently have various notifications triggered by various events that I am sending via email or OneSignal. But I want users to see notifications appear in near real time on the site when they are logged in, regardless of the means by which I sent the message.

Lately I have been revisiting a notification system that I implemented on my previous site that I built with Laravel and trying to figure out how to adapt for WordPress. Here is what I do on the Laravel site (a lot of it based on this great tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/add-real-time-notifications-laravel-pusher/).

```
var notificationsWrapper   = $('.dropdown-notifications');
var notificationsToggle    = notificationsWrapper.find('a[data-toggle]');
var notificationsCountElem = notificationsToggle.find('i[data-count]');
var notificationsCount     = parseInt(notificationsCountElem.data('count'));

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

import Echolibrary from "laravel-echo";

var notifications = [];

const NOTIFICATION_TYPES = {
    follow: 'App\\Notifications\\UserFollowed',
    newEx: 'App\\Notifications\\NewExercisePosted'
};

window.Echo = new Echolibrary({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    cluster: 'mt1',
    encrypted: true
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    if(Laravel.userId) {
        // load notifications from database
        $.get(`/notifications`, function (data) {
            addNotifications(data, "#notifications", 'db');
        });

        // load new ones from pusher
        Echo.private(`App.User.${Laravel.userId}`)
            .notification((notification) => {
            addNotifications([notification], '#notifications', 'pusher');
    });
    }
});

function addNotifications(newNotifications, target, source) {
    notifications = _.concat(notifications, newNotifications);
    // show only last 5 notifications
    notifications.slice(0, 5);
    showNotifications(notifications, target);
}

function showNotifications(notifications, target) {
    notificationsCount = notifications.length;
    notificationsCountElem.attr('data-count', notificationsCount);
    if(notifications.length) {
        var htmlElements = notifications.map(function (notification) {
            return makeNotification(notification);
        });

        $('#markall').show();
        $(target + 'Header').after(htmlElements.join(''));
        $(target).addClass('has-notifications');
        $('#nomsgs').hide();


    } else {
        $('#markall').hide();
        $(target + 'Header').after('<li class="dropdown-header" id="nomsgs">No messages</li>');
        $(target).removeClass('has-notifications');
    }
}

// Make a single notification string
function makeNotification(notification) {
    var to = routeNotification(notification);
    var notificationText = makeNotificationText(notification);
    return '<li class = "msgitems" style="background-color:white; border-style:solid; border-width: 1px; border-color:#2073a2; margin: 2px; padding:0px"><a style="color:blue;" href="' + to + '">' + notificationText + '</a></li>';
}

function routeNotification(notification) {
    var to = `?read=${notification.id}`;
    if(notification.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES.follow) {
        to = 'users' + to;
    } else if(notification.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES.newEx) {
        const exId = notification.data.ex_id;
        to = `guitar-lesson-ex/${exId}` + to;
    }
    return '/' + to;
}


function makeNotificationText(notification) {
    var text = '';
    if(notification.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES.follow) {
        const name = notification.data.follower_name;
        text += `<strong>${name}</strong> followed you`;
    } else if(notification.type === NOTIFICATION_TYPES.newEx) {
        text += `<img src = "/img/guitarpick.png" alt = "guitar pick">  New exercise: ` + notification.data.title;
    }
    return text;
}

$("#markall").click(function () {

    var targetHref = $(this).data('href');

    $.post('/markallnotificationsread', function (data) {
        data.success ? (window.location.href = targetHref) : false;
    }, 'json');

    notificationsCountElem.attr('data-count', 0);
    $('#notificationsHeader').nextAll().remove();
    $('#notificationsHeader').after('<li class="dropdown-header" id ="nomsgs">No messages</li>');
    $('#notifications').removeClass('has-notifications');
    $('#markall').hide();

    return false;
});
```

To do this in WordPress, should I take same approach, meaning import the Laravel Echo library or should I be thinking in different direction?

Also, in my current case, I have certain notifications that

1. go to a user (like 'your course access expires soon'), and
2. go to a group (like 'your course is now open')

For case 1, is pusher even a good use case, since this is not really a channel sort of message, but a one-off to a single user?

Anyway, curious if maybe there is a completely different, better way you would go about this.